# Get the calculation of Smith-Waterman over 100 %

Tags: java, algorithm, bioinformatics

I wrote some Java code that has implemented Smith-Waterman algorithm. I have a journal entry [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6615411&queryText%3DAST+-based+Multi-language+Plagiarism+Detection+Method) that said like this

```
sim  (X, Y)  = 2 . SLength  (X, Y) / Length  ( X)  +  Length  (Y  ) 


X  and  Y are  the  sequences  for  comparison.  
SLength(X, Y) is  the  string length of the  maximum matching set.  
Length(X) is the  number  of  characters  in  the  sequence X.
Length(Y)  is  the     number  of  characters  in  the  sequence  Y.  
The  result  of  this function (sim)  is a real  number,  O<=sim<=1.  
The larger  SIM is, the  stronger  the  two  programs  similarity  is,
and  the  plagiarism possibility larger,  vice versa.
```

Here is my Smith-Waterman code

```
public class SmithWaterman {

private final String one, two;
private final int matrix[][];
private int gap;
private final int match;
private final int o;
private int l;
private final int e;

public SmithWaterman(String one, String two) {
    this.one = "-" + one.toLowerCase();
    this.two = "-" + two.toLowerCase();
    this.match = 2;

    // Define affine gap starting values
    o = -2;
    l = -1;
    e = -1;

    // initialize matrix to 0
    matrix = new int[one.length() + 1][two.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < one.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < two.length(); j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

}

// returns the alignment score
/**
 * @return
 */
public double computeSmithWaterman() {
    for (int i = 0; i < one.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < two.length(); j++) {
            gap = o + (l - 1) * e;
            if (i != 0 && j != 0) {
                if (one.charAt(i) == two.charAt(j)) {
                    // match
                    // reset l
                    l = 0;
                    matrix[i][j] = Math.max(0, Math.max(
                            matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + match, Math.max(
                                    matrix[i - 1][j] + gap,
                                    matrix[i][j - 1] + gap)));
                } else {
                    // gap
                    l++;
                    matrix[i][j] = Math.max(0, Math.max(
                            matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + gap, Math.max(
                                    matrix[i - 1][j] + gap,
                                    matrix[i][j - 1] + gap)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // find the highest value
    double longest = 0;
    int iL = 0, jL = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < one.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < two.length(); j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] > longest) {
                longest = matrix[i][j];
                iL = i;
                jL = j;
            }
        }
    }

    // Backtrack to reconstruct the path
    int i = iL;
    int j = jL;
    Stack<String> actions = new Stack<String>();

    while (i != 0 && j != 0) {
        // diag case
        if (Math.max(matrix[i - 1][j - 1],
                Math.max(matrix[i - 1][j], matrix[i][j - 1])) == matrix[i - 1][j - 1]) {
            actions.push("align");
            i = i - 1;
            j = j - 1;
            // left case
        } else if (Math.max(matrix[i - 1][j - 1],
                Math.max(matrix[i - 1][j], matrix[i][j - 1])) == matrix[i][j - 1]) {
            actions.push("insert");
            j = j - 1;
            // up case
        } else {
            actions.push("delete");
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }

    int maxMatchSet = actions.size();

    String alignOne = new String();
    String alignTwo = new String();

    Stack<String> backActions = (Stack<String>) actions.clone();
    for (int z = 0; z < one.length(); z++) {
        alignOne = alignOne + one.charAt(z);
        if (!actions.empty()) {
            String curAction = actions.pop();

            if (curAction.equals("insert")) {
                alignOne = alignOne + "-";
                while (actions.peek().equals("insert")) {
                    alignOne = alignOne + "-";
                    actions.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < two.length(); z++) {
        alignTwo = alignTwo + two.charAt(z);
        if (!backActions.empty()) {
            String curAction = backActions.pop();
            if (curAction.equals("delete")) {
                alignTwo = alignTwo + "-";
                while (backActions.peek().equals("delete")) {
                    alignTwo = alignTwo + "-";
                    backActions.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int minMatchSet = backActions.size();

    // print alignment
    double realLengthStringOne = one.length() - 1;
    double realLenghtStringTwo = two.length() - 1;
    double totalOfMatricesElement = realLengthStringOne + realLenghtStringTwo;

    double value = (2 * maxMatchSet / totalOfMatricesElement) * 100;

    System.out.println("2 * " + maxMatchSet + " / " + "( " + realLengthStringOne + " + " + realLenghtStringTwo + " ) " + "= " + value + "%");


    return value;
}

public void printMatrix() {

    for (int i = 0; i < one.length(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            for (int z = 0; z < two.length(); z++) {
                if (z == 0) {
                    System.out.print("  \t");
                }
                System.out.print(two.charAt(z) + " \t");

                if (z == two.length() - 1) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < two.length(); j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.print(one.charAt(i) + " \t");
            }
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " \t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // DNA sequence Test:

    SmithWaterman sw = new SmithWaterman("ahmad", "achmad");
    System.out.println("Alignment Score: " + sw.computeSmithWaterman());

    sw.printMatrix();

}
}
```

if I have two sequence like "ahmad", "ahmad" , the output is = 100 %,

but you know, if I have two sequence like "ahmad", "achmad" ,the output is like this :

```
2 * 6 / ( 5.0 + 6.0 ) = 109.09090909090908%

Alignment Score: 109.09090909090908
  -     a   c   h   m   a   d   
-   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
a   0   2   1   0   0   2   1   
h   0   0   0   3   2   0   0   
m   0   0   0   0   5   4   2   
a   0   2   1   0   2   7   6   
d   0   0   0   0   0   1   9
```

Have I am worng in implementation, where am I lost ini the code ?

Comment: You have two separate problems: 1) your match score is +2, so that two matching strings with length 3 gives you a score of 6, and you used this score as the length of the match; 2) your string length calculation included the `'-'` you added to each string, so that in your test example, you counted the strings as of length 4 each instead of 3.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your immediate question why you got 150%

your variable `longest = 6` and your set your values `one` and `two` to actually be `'-' + one` and `'-'+ two` respectively so the math was  `2 * 6 / 8 = 12 /8 = 1.5` * 100 = 150%.

You might be able to get the correct answer if you use the original lengths of `one` and `two`.

However, I think your approach may be flawed:

Your variable `longest` isn't the length of the match but the highest score in your matrix.  This is the Smith-Waterman alignment score.  This works out for now because you are aligning a perfect match and use a match score of `+2` however I'm not sure this will work for non-perfect matches.

This value represents the best scoring (partial) alignment path through the matrix.  While this path is often the longest path, it doesn't have to be.  There could be a longer but worse scoring path elsewhere.

Furthermore your match penalty of open gap `-2` and extension `-1` means multiple consecutive gaps will make your match score no longer an even number.

To actually see how long your alignment is, you must actually track back through your matrix starting at your highest scoring location until you get to a cell in the matrix with a score of `0`. (Since this is Smith-Waterman which allows for local alignments opposed to full length global alignments).

You already do something similar to this in your `actions` block of code.  However you may want to take into account how insertions and deletions are considered as part of the length.  If you want to count them then the longest alignment length is just `actions.size()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have changed type of "longest" variable. It should be *int*; you are using it as *double*.

It like below:

```
System.out.println(12.0/8);
System.out.println(12/8);
```

Output would be:

```
 1.5  
 1
```

as variable is double result will also be double but if you will use int result will also be double.

Comment: I don't think truncating the answer help the OP understand why the algorithm might be wrong.